# Woocommerce cart cleared programmatically but no changes on frontside

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing an api for woocommerce. when I call clear cart on my api it runs the code below:

```
 wp_set_current_user($userid);
 WC()->cart->empty_cart();
 WC()->session->set('cart', array());
```

It works well and the changes are made to the database but if the user's already logged on, it won't update the cart until the user logs out and logs in again. I also tested Woocommerce REST API but same story.
Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?
Thanks